# Show each matplotlib graph in a new window

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

I have created a code that shows me graphs based on coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

draws = [['4X13' , 0.105,  0.103,  0.008,  0.007,  0.088],
        ['5X16'  , 0.127,  0.127,  0.009,  0.006,  0.108],
        ['5X19'  , 0.130,  0.127,  0.010,  0.006,  0.108],
        ['6X8.5' , 0.148,  0.100,  0.004,  0.004,  0.138],
        ['6X9'   , 0.149,  0.100,  0.005,  0.004,  0.138],
        ['6X12'  , 0.153,  0.101,  0.007,  0.005,  0.138]]

for i in range(len(draws)):   
    xi_down = 0
    yi_down = 0
    xf_down = draws[i][2]
    yf_down = 0

    xi_up = 0
    yi_up = draws[i][1]
    xf_up = draws[i][2]
    yf_up = draws[i][1]


    xi_mid = draws[i][2]/2
    yi_mid = 0
    xf_mid = draws[i][2]/2
    yf_mid = draws[i][1]

    plt.plot((xi_down, xf_down), (yi_down, yf_down), linewidth = draws[i][3]*1000)
    plt.plot((xi_up, xf_up), (yi_up, yf_up), linewidth = draws[i][3]*1000)
    plt.plot((xi_mid, xf_mid), (yi_mid, yf_mid), linewidth = draws[i][4]*1000)

    plt.title('P W '+draws[i][0])
    plt.axis('equal')

    plt.show()
```

The problem is that each graph is mounted on top of each other, what I want is for them to be shown in separate windows, something like this:

[images_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24WwS.png)

One solution could be to call the plot methods for each row in the list again but I think it would be inefficient, is there a better method?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the following line at the start of each iteration:

```
for i in range(len(draws)):
    plt.figure()
    ...
```

And if you want to see all the plot open, remove the following line from the loop:

```
plt.show()
```

This will generate a figure object, and when you will use the plot in each iteration it will appear in different window.

The entire code that generates 6 plot figures is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

draws = [['4X13' , 0.105,  0.103,  0.008,  0.007,  0.088],
        ['5X16'  , 0.127,  0.127,  0.009,  0.006,  0.108],
        ['5X19'  , 0.130,  0.127,  0.010,  0.006,  0.108],
        ['6X8.5' , 0.148,  0.100,  0.004,  0.004,  0.138],
        ['6X9'   , 0.149,  0.100,  0.005,  0.004,  0.138],
        ['6X12'  , 0.153,  0.101,  0.007,  0.005,  0.138]]

for i in range(len(draws)):
    plt.figure()
    xi_down = 0
    yi_down = 0
    xf_down = draws[i][2]
    yf_down = 0

    xi_up = 0
    yi_up = draws[i][1]
    xf_up = draws[i][2]
    yf_up = draws[i][1]


    xi_mid = draws[i][2]/2
    yi_mid = 0
    xf_mid = draws[i][2]/2
    yf_mid = draws[i][1]

    plt.plot((xi_down, xf_down), (yi_down, yf_down), linewidth = draws[i][3]*1000)
    plt.plot((xi_up, xf_up), (yi_up, yf_up), linewidth = draws[i][3]*1000)
    plt.plot((xi_mid, xf_mid), (yi_mid, yf_mid), linewidth = draws[i][4]*1000)

    plt.title('P W '+draws[i][0])
    plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent and practical explanation @David S.